# Not able to load data from HDFS to Hive in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am new to hadoop and in the learning phase. When I am trying to execute the below statement in hive, the `empl.txt` is being moved to trash folder.

```
load data inpath '/user/trnkimz/empl.txt' into table empl;
```

Also, the data is not getting stored in the empl table.
In my empl table, I am having the below columns: `e-id int` and `e_name String`.

In my `empl.txt` file, I am having the below data in it:

```
1,john
2,smith
3,alex
```

Kindly suggest, that why I am not able to load data from HDFS to hive table.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: - Check that /user/trnkimz/empl.txt is on HDFS, if it is on your local filesystem, use LOAD LOCAL DATA .

- Also, make sure the table has the correct 'ROW FORMAT DELIMITED', check at: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RowFormat,StorageFormat,andSerDe

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check whether you are having your input file in local or hdfs .

If it is in **local** means you have to use LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/username/inputfile' into table TABLENAME   (this is equal to copyFromLocal)

If it is in **HDFS** means you have to use LOAD DATA INPATH '/inputfile' into table TABLENAME  (this is equal to mv command in hdfs)

Answer (score 0):

we can load data to a hive table in 2 ways

1) load table with data with local data

hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE  ;

2) load table with data with HDFS data

hive> LOAD DATA INPATH '' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE  ;